# F# Extra parameter List.map

Tags: f#

I'm having big trouble getting the List.map function to run. 
I have a list of tuples:

```
let list = [
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c")
]
```

I want to use it here:

```
let FooBar (x: int) =
    list |> List.map (fun (num, word) number -> if number % num = 0 then word else "") x 
    |> String.concat "" wordList
```

But I cannot get this to work. I need all three parameters (num + word of each list entry and the x) within the function. 
I'm glad for any advise and hints

Got it working like this:

```
let list = [
    (1, "a");
    (2, "b");
    (3, "c")
]

let convert (number: int) = 
    let wordList = List.map (fun (num, word) -> if number % num = 0 then word else "") numWord
```

Comment: To be a list of tuples, you should separate each tuple using a semicolon, not a comma as in your example: let list = [(1, "a");(2, "b");(3, "c")]. Otherwise, you would have a list with only a single element (a tuple of tuples).

Comment: Oh noooo! That was the big issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The definition of your projection is here: `(fun (num, word) -> >do sth<)`. `x` stands outside and thus treated as an parameter to the `List.map`.
Just change your code in the following way:
`(fun (num, word) -> num, word, x)`. That would give you a projection that takes some pair of `(num, word)` and maps it to a triplet `(num, word, x)`.

Here is a bit more elegant way:

```
let enrich z (x, y) = x, y, z
let fooBar x = List.map (enrich x)
```

Comment: But the goal is not to just enrich the tuple to a triplet. The do sth part is another function that does something. How do you I get all three parameters in there?
I included my code in the goal

Comment: @HmmRfa you gon there already. `(fun (x, y) -> <body_of_the_lambda_goes_here>)`. You can do whatever you want inside that lambda. Just use proper indentation in case of multiline code. All the parameters are there: you can see first and second elements of a pair and access whatever defined in a outter scope as well as in any programming language.